# perl push array and get in order

Tags: perl

I push some objects into array

```
my $temp1= Gene->new("id" => $temp[0],"name"=>$temp[1],"chrom"=>$temp[2], "strand"=>$temp[3],"txStart"=>$temp[4], "txEnd"=>$temp[5],"cdsStart"=>$temp[6],"cdsEnd"=>$temp[7],"exonCount"=>$temp[8],"exonStarts"=>$temp[9],"exonEnds"=>$temp[10],"score"=>$temp[11],"name2"=>$temp[12],"cdsStartStat"=>$temp[13],"cdsEndStat"=>$temp[14],"exonFrames"=>$temp[15]);


push(@genes,$temp1);
```

but when i use for loop to get each objects in array,

```
for(my $t=0; $t <= $genes; $t++){   
my $g=$genes[$t];
my $k = -1;
print $g->get_name,"\n";
```

It seems no by order. the origin one is

```
 NR_046018
 NR_024540
 NR_106918
 NR_107062
 NR_036051
 .....
```

but when i print name it seems random output in for loop

```
 NR_046018
 NR_106918
 NR_036051
 NR_036267
 NR_026820
 NR_039983
 NM_001005221
```

Comment: What is difference between the generation of the last two lists? Or could you please show both?

Comment: Why do you not use `foreach my $g (@genes) { ... `?

Comment: I believe you have been already advised to `use strict;` in your past questions?

Comment: the sequence is different

Comment: yes it works use foreach, why use for(my $t=0; $t <= $genes; $t++) has this problem. @LeeDuhem  Thanks

Comment: @JesseSiu No idea. Did you try to print the value of `$t` in the beginning of your `for` loop? That may give you some clues.

Comment: I guess you are modifying the array `@genes` inside the loop. Please show your complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(my $t=0; $t <= $genes; $t++)
```

should be

```
for(my $t=0; $t <= $#genes; $t++)
```

and `use strict;` would give you a hint regarding this typo.